# Value cannot be null, r nparameter name source

Tags: c#, linq

I am confused. I have two statements that are the same and one works and the other receives the error - *value cannot be null. r nparameter name source.* From what I read I am receiving the error because something is null in my linq expression. However from what I can tell nothing is null.

The first if statement works. When a person selects 'Select' from a list of Burn Project a list of BurnPiles is displayed below the BurnProject list. (this works). Then when a person selects 'Select' from the list of BurnPiles a list of RequestedBurns is display below it. This gives me the null error. At one time it did work now it doesn't.

I am at a loss of what went wrong. I do know the RequestedBurn Table starts at record #2 but that shouldn't have anything to do with it. The BurnPile records that I have been using have associated RequestedBurns.

```
        //when 'Select' is chosen from the list of burn projects the list of burn piles 
        //associated with that specific burn project is display below it.
        if (burnerID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.BurnerID = burnerID.Value;
            viewModel.BurnPiles = viewModel.BurnProjects.Where(
                b => b.BurnerID == burnerID.Value).Single().BurnPiles;
        }

        //when 'Select' is chosen from the list of burn piles the list of requested 
        //burns associated with that specific burn pile is displayed below it.
        if (burnPileID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.BurnPilesID = burnPileID.Value;
            viewModel.RequestedBurns = viewModel.BurnPiles.Where(
                x => x.BurnPilesID == burnPileID).Single().RequestedBurns;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewModel.BurnPiles = viewModel.BurnProjects.Where(
            b => b.BurnerID == burnerID.Value).Single().BurnPiles;
```

could be setting viewModel.BurnPiles to null.

or

```
viewModel.BurnPiles.Where(
            x => x.BurnPilesID == burnPileID).Single()
```

is returning nothing so when you try and access RequestedBurns then it throws an exception.

Comment: in the Index view the 'Select' passes the burnPileID to the second if statement *<td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { burnPileID = item.BurnPilesID })
                </td>*

Comment: It was passing a null to *viewModel.RequestedBurns = viewModel.BurnPile ....* so on the 'Select' where I pass the burnPiles parameter to call the RequestedBurns I included the parameter burnID to make sure the first viewModel.BurnPiles in the 1st If statement had a value to pass through to the next. -- Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you look at documentation for [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx), you would see that `source` is the name of the parameter that represents your collection. So, it looks like you are trying to call a method on `null` reference, which would be the case if `viewModel.BurnProjects = null` or `viewModel.BurnPiles = null`.

Comment: is there a way I can remedy this?

Comment: Check whether they are null before calling Where or Single methods

Answer (score 1):

`SingleOrDefault` also has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can simplify the expression a bit more. You can also combine it with the null conditional operator (if using at least C# 6).

```
if (burnerID != null)
{
    ViewBag.BurnerID = burnerID.Value;
    viewModel.BurnPiles = viewModel.BurnProjects.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BurnerID == burnerID.Value)?.BurnPiles;
}
```

Comment: when I try this I receive *invalid expression* on the '.' and *Syntax error Expected '.'* on BurnPiles

Comment: Are you using C#6? (VS2015?)

Comment: Stupid question however where do I look? From the Visual Studios about it list Visual C# 2013

Comment: Help menu -> About Microsoft Visual Studio is where you can find information. Unfortunately you cannot use that feature because it was added in C#6, which shipped with Visual Studio 2015.